# PHP Insert Multiple image filename

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, upload

I have a form that is using an AJAX image upload function, but I want the form to upload the image & thumbnail (which its doing perfectly), but, I want that image filename to be written into my MySQL database (using PHP).

my test file (to see the upload/component) is at http://www.spearman.co.za/admin/stackoverflow.php?id=100  -  ive removed any INSERT clause, so this shows just the upload component.

I have figured a way to insert a single image into db  (used `GetSQLValueString($_POST['images4ex'] [0], "text"),`  in my INSERT INTO clause),  but, im wondering how to run a loop for when someone uploads multiple images.

Ive tried to use 30 ideas/snippet Ive seen on this forum but, my coding knowledge isnt great.  It uploads the image but doesnt write the file into the database.

My database table is simple & has 2 fields:
Tablename:  NEW_extrapropertyimg
field:  image (for the image filename)
field:  propertyid (this is a passed URL variable so I can filter with this id)

I have a hidden field for the propertyid using `<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>`
My AJAX select box is `<div id="images4ex" name="images4ex[]" orakuploader="on" ></div>`

It seems I need to do an array or an implode - which I dont know how to even start.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: show your code you tried.

Comment: Hiya .. ok, Ive tried this -  it does upload & thumnail images, it is also inserting into the database ... but, it puts all the image filenames in a single row.


`<?php


$values = implode("",$_POST[images4ex]); 

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO NEW_extrapropertyimg(image) 

VALUES('$values')") or die(mysql_error());

  echo "Success.";


?>`


It inserts to the database '1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg4.jpg'


Im not sure how to split it so it inserts each file uploaded into a new row, or, how to add the propertyid onto this.

Answer (score 0):

If the $_POST["images4ex"] contains all the image names, and you want to insert those in the database, you can loop the $_POST[images4ex] using a foreach for example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["images4ex"])) {
    foreach ($_POST["images4ex"] as $image4ex) {
        // In this loop, the $image4ex should be the image name so you can perform your insert query here.
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for that -  I did try your suggestion, but, its still puts the files names of the images into a single row (ie:  1.jpg2.jpg3.jpg ).

Is there a way to make each image insert as a new record/row?

Comment: You have added something like this in the loop?
`mysql_query("INSERT INTO NEW_extrapropertyimg(image) VALUES('$image4ex')") or die(mysql_error());`
Maybe you can check the contents of the $_POST array before the loop to make sure there are multiple values for 'images4ex'. You can use `var_dump($_POST);`
Because you are doing an asynchronous call, you can see the output of this var_dump in the http call to the server in [firefox firebug net panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) or [chrome Network](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

Comment: thanks man, 

Ive played around my side, using some ideas, Ive managed to get it to send each image filename to the database into a new record with script below.

`for ($i = 0, $len = count($_POST['images4ex']); $i < $len; $i++) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO NEW_extrapropertyimg (propertyid, image) VALUES (%s, %s)",
GetSQLValueString($_POST['propertyid'][$i], "text"),
GetSQLValueString($_POST['images4ex'][$i], "text"));`

but, it only adds URL propertyid onto 1 of the entry.
Any idea how to get that variable to be written into all the entries?

Comment: I can see why the propertyID value wasnt inserting ... removed the `[$i]`  from `GetSQLValueString($_POST['propertyid'][$i], "text"), `
Functions perfectly now.

Do you guys know how to extract the index value of the uploaded file?
Say if I have 10 files I upload, 10 files I insert to db .. how would you pull the index number of each file?

1.jpg  -  propertyid100 - orderID 1

Comment: If you mean how to get the "1" from "1.jpg", you can do that in multiple ways. 2 examples: If `$photo = "1.jpg";`, you could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
`$number = explode(".", $photo)[0];` Or you can use [mb_strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) with [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) `$position = mb_strpos($photo, ".");$number = mb_substr($photo, 0, $position);`